# how to Ceate ObjectAnimator animation to mp4 Video?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-annotations

I am trying to Create ObjectAnimator animation to m4 video .

Anybody give me solution ?

**ObjectAnimator animation** CODE :

```
 public void animation(){

    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "alpha", 0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "translationY", -700f, 0f);
    mover.setDuration(1000);

    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "alpha", 0.8f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    // animatorSet.play(mover).with(fadeIn).after(fadeOut);
    animatorSet.play(fadeOut).after(mover).with(fadeIn);
    animatorSet.start();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the public void animation(){ in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can not create ObjectAnimator to video. You can only animate `View` that will used to show the video.

Comment: please tell me process . how can ?